# Can not connect to VM instance via SSH

Tags: ssh, cloud, virtual-machine, instance

Today I found out I can not connect to my VM instance via SSH anymore.
I have checked and even re-added firewall rule to open port 22, yet I see the port is closed. I have done nothing that I can recollect that could have ended up closing that port.

I have also tried logging in via serial port, but I have no login password for that (I always let google just log me in with key).

Can anyone help me?